# Debugging WebApi2 Login (/Token) endpoint

Tags: oauth, asp.net-web-api2

Using .NET WebApi2:
I am getting an 500 internal server error when attempting to log in to a WebApi, at the **/Token 
endpoint.**

I know there are some configuration parameters in Startup.Auth, but **is there anyway I can set a breakpoint, or otherwise see what is showing up on the server?** (say, before the authentication check happens, and after -- not looking for a Fiddler type intercept solution).

Comment: Unless you are using a custom OAuth provider you can't put a breakpoint in as far as i can tell. Unless the code is open source and you can download the project and import it into your solution. Is there no way for you to get the details of the exception another way? For example using elmah or turning off custom error messages?

Comment: thanks for the suggestions - I tried debugging by setting custom errors off inside webapiconfig...saw it was a "SystemInvalidOperation Exception" but that didn't help much. I'll try ELMAH, hadn't heard of it before. Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 16):

debug **GrantResourceOwnerCredentials** method in Providers/ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs

Comment: If the OP has the same problem as me, then the error occurs after `TokenEndpoint`, but before `TokenEndpointResponse`, so a custom `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` implementation doesn't help. For me, this is only on Linux running mono 3 and 4.

Comment: I have put a breakpoint in that function and it doesn't even hit. This means its returning the error before it even calls this.

Comment: In my case it is returning data fine after login but i want to put return more details but breakpoint does not come at this function

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Visual Studio to break on all exceptions and then obtain more information about your error when it throws.

In Visual Studio 2013, debug menu, Exceptions, mark both ckecks related to CLR exceptions as shown in the image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can debug it... but you need to implement your own *ApplicationOAuthProvider* which should inherit from this class: *OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider*

For example:

```
 public class MyTokenProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    private readonly string _publicClientId;

    public MyTokenProvider(string publicClientId)
    {
        if (publicClientId == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("publicClientId");
        }

        _publicClientId = publicClientId;
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
           OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
    }

    public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
        {
            context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        // Resource owner password credentials does not provide a client ID.
        if (context.ClientId == null)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)
    {
        if (context.ClientId == _publicClientId)
        {
            Uri expectedRootUri = new Uri(context.Request.Uri, "/");

            if (expectedRootUri.AbsoluteUri == context.RedirectUri)
            {
                context.Validated();
            }
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(string userName)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "userName", userName }
        };
        return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
    }
}
```

Obviously you will need to set it as your default provider, and that could be done from your **Startup.Auth.cs**

Example:

```
            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new MyTokenProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
```

Then you can debug it :)